# How inherit BaseController behaviors in child controller, because Base behaviours has priority by Childe behaviours?

Tags: yii2

For example? I have two BaseController and ChildController.
I want attach behaviors from BaseController, but priority has behaviors(Base), when behaviors(Child).

Base:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'allow' => true,
                        'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) { 
                            return ...(true or false)...;
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Child:

```
                    [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin'],
                    'matchCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
                        return ... can...
                    }
                ],
```

and logic:

if parent return false then access denied

if parent return true then what return child

how?

Answer (score 0):

This must help you

```
  public function behaviors()
  {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['access'] = [
      'class' => AccessControl::className(),
      'rules' => [
        [
          'allow' => true,
          'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
            return ... can ...;
          },
        ],
      ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;
  }
```

other way could be:

```
public function behaviors()
  {
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
    $behaviors['access']['rules'][] = [
      'allow' => true,
      'matchCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
        return ... can ...;
      },
    ];
    return $behaviors;
  }
```